# openSUSE install Oracle JDK error

Tags: java-8, opensuse

OS: openSUSE Leap 42.3

When I install OracleJDK error!

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh jdk-8u151-linux-x64.rpm
[sudo] root 的密码：
准备中...                          ################################# [100%]
正在升级/安装...
   1:jdk1.8-2000:1.8.0_151-fcs        ################################# [100%]
Unpacking JAR files...
        tools.jar...
        plugin.jar...
        javaws.jar...
        deploy.jar...
        rt.jar...
        jsse.jar...
        charsets.jar...
        localedata.jar...
update-alternatives: error: alternative pack200 can't be slave of java: it is a slave of javac
update-alternatives: error: alternative keytool can't be slave of javac: it is a slave of java
警告：%post(jdk1.8-2000:1.8.0_151-fcs.x86_64) 脚本执行失败，退出状态码为 2
```

In fact, Java files have been written to the hard disk.

````
$ ls -l /usr/java 
总用量 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 12月  9 14:08 default -> /usr/java/latest
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 284 12月  9 14:08 jdk1.8.0_151
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  22 12月  9 14:08 latest -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151
```
````

But, the Java version does not switch.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.6.0) (build 1.8.0_151-b12 suse-18.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

I can not use `update-alternatives` to switch Java versions without doing anything else.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

So, I want to know:

1. Why is there such a mistake, all openSUSE version will have such a problem?
2. What is the most formal way to switch Java versions?

Comment: there is an utility called `jenv` - may be that can help?